# How can I make sure if some HTML elements are loaded for Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

From this link, I assume the DOM should be loaded as a whole at first in RAM.

[How DOM works/is loaded? (in HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423864/how-dom-works-is-loaded-in-html)

But then I test in Selenium with a timeout exception. It seems even the timeout exception is raised, some elements can already be found, so it is not an empty object.

But I am wondering, how can I make sure some elements are already loaded? E.g. the HTML example, how can I make sure all `<th>` elements are loaded? Given the fact that I actually do not know the number of the `<th>` elements.

Code trial :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
try:
    driver.get(url)
    print('load success!')
except TimeoutException:
    print(self.page_source)
```

Sample HTML:

```
<table width="910" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="fth1_" class="fth1_" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 29px; left: 99px;">
     <thead style="background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);">
        <tr align="center">
           <th id="f13" style="width: 121px;"><a href="t/?i=614&amp;o=1">Symbol</a></th>
           <th id="f13" style="width: 267px;"><a href="t/?i=614&amp;o=2">Name</a></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code trials you are using *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* to *Automate* the steps. As you have configured `set_page_load_timeout(10)` the *timeout* exception is raised as the page havn't completely loaded within the timeframe configured through `set_page_load_timeout()`. But as you have invoked `print(self.page_source)` the elements rendered within the partially rendered [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) are retrieved.

Now about your individual queries :

- `How can I make sure some elements are already loaded?` : An ideal *testcase* would have a definite step e.g. to validate the presence of an element, to validate the visibility of an element or to validate the interactability (while clicking) of element. From this perspective verifying the *elements are already loaded* may not include the desired element. Hence instead of such a *broader search criteria* you need to narrow down your *search criteria* to some thing definite e.g.

  - *Page Title*
  - *Page Heading*
  - *Presence of an Alert*
  - *Attribute of an element*
  - *Presence of an element*
  - *Presence of a group of elements*
  - *Visibility of an element*
  - *Visibility of a group of elements*
  - *Clickablity of an element*
  - *StalenessOf of an element*
  - *FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*

Implementing these  narrowed down *search criteria* can save a lot of *execution time* with the help of [**`WebDriverWait`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [**`expected_conditions`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).

- `How can I make sure all elements are loaded?` : Again, our tests should be focused only on the element/elements  with which we need to interact with and leaveout verifying the status/condition of other elements which are not of our interest.
- Now, following the two points mentioned above these are the 3 most commonly used *usecases* :

  - [**`presence_of_element_located`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) : An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
  - [**`visibility_of_element_located`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) : An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
  - [**`element_to_be_clickable`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) : An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
- As per the *usecase* you mentioned you can make a *List* of all the `<th>` elements visible within the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) whilst waiting for a configurable amount of time inducing *WebDriverWait* as follows :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

  headerList = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='fth1_' and @id='fth1_']/thead/tr//th")))
  ```

> **Note** : The *xpath* used in this illustration is a sample *xpath* used only for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Thnx, the answer is not rly what I want, but just got to know I can so many properties of the DOM element in selenium. Many thnx.

Comment: How is this different from driver's implicit or explicit timeouts?

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't work. I am yet to understand why. Could you share some thoughts on where it may not work? Even after implementing everything, I am still getting StaleElementReferenceException (but only in some cases, and on retry, it gets resolved randomly). I am applying this on <select> tag options. If you need more elaboration, I will create a question separately.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by checking the loading behavior of HTML.

Basically the HTML loads upside down, that said, I just have to check if a elemet behind the  elemt, e.g. if another element comes after , just check if another element is presented or not. If yes, then all the  elements must be loaded.