# Non-deterministic behavior of ChromeDriver and Chrome with pageLoadStrategy none

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I have a web crawler using Selenium and Chromium running on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.  All new crawling requests come in to Apache/WSGI, which creates a new python thread for each request and spawns Chromium process with pyvirtualdisplay and Xvfb to load the website, login, take screenshots, etc.

I use Chromium with the flags:
disable-extensions, disable-gpu, headless, no-sandbox

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
```

I then have a function that checks every second to see if the page is loaded yet (as some of the pages don't fully load within a reasonable time, so I try to wait until they're at least interactive before proceeding):

```
driver.execute_script("var state = document.readyState; return state;")
```

The weird thing is that now when I try to load a page, it immediately says it's in state 'complete' (and continues to be so for the next 15 seconds).  But when I actually try to find an element, it can't be found - so I don't think it's actually loaded.  Normally it will say it's 'loading' and then 'interactive', etc.

I've tried restarting Apache, but doesn't seem to have fixed anything.  What could be wrong?

I can see in my process list that Chromium and Xvfb are indeed running when the new request comes in:

```
7429 ?        S      0:00 Xvfb -br -nolisten tcp -screen 0 1024x768x24 :2165
7430 ?        Sl     0:00 /var/www/html/flaskapp/chromedriver --port=39146
7438 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing
7440 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote --no-sandbox --enable-logging --headless --log-l
7457 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --enable-logging --headless --
7468 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
7469 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --no-sandbox --enable-automation --enable-logg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the **ChromeDriver** with the required parameters. A few points:

- If you are at all waiting until the elements are at least interactive before proceeding then there is no point in configuring:

  ```
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  ```
- A better approach would be to either configure `pageLoadStrategy` as **`normal`** or stick to the default policy removing the configuration all together:

  ```
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion in:

  - [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script)
  - [Page load strategy for Chrome driver (Updated till Selenium v3.12.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0)
- `pageLoadStrategy` as **`eager`** is yet to be implemented in *Chrome*.
- You can find a detailed discussion in:

  - [Re: [chromedriver] Add page loading strategy to capabilities (issue 2125123002 by evaj...@google.com)](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/devtools-reviews/Hu74sHnkWcM)
  - [Issue 2125123002: [chromedriver] Add page loading strategy to capabilities (Closed)](https://codereview.chromium.org/2125123002/)
- So to ensure that your desired elements are loaded you need to induce *WebDriverWait* as per the prevailing conditions as detailed out in the discussion [How can I make sure if some HTML elements are loaded for Selenium + Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154940/how-can-i-make-sure-if-some-html-elements-are-loaded-for-selenium-python)