# c# Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor scrolling down does not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've got a problem, because I need to scroll down the page, 
so I decided to use `IJavaScriptExecutor`

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js =  (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
```

I also tried

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", invite); 

js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the problem? what happened when you tried it?

Comment: nothing happened. IJavaScriptExecutor was simply ignored by the program.
That's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Before you attempt to scroll down a page ensure that the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) have rendered completely. 
Here you can find a detailed discussion [How can I make sure if some HTML elements are loaded for Selenium + Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154940/how-can-i-make-sure-if-some-html-elements-are-loaded-for-selenium-python)

Once the *Page Load* is completed you can invoke the `scroll()` methods as follows:

- To scroll down 250 pixcels:

  ```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
  js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
  ```
- To scroll down the entire page:

  ```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
  js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
  ```
- To scroll an element into view:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("css_element")));
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
  js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
  ```

Comment: So, I need to make a method, for example which will wait for example 30 seconds to make a part of site's head visible, and then invoke the scroll() method? Right?

Comment: @MariuszBudzisz You don't need a function but a simple instance of WebDriverWait. That would do.

Comment: public void Invite(){
var span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 60, 0);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, span);
wait.Until(foo => foo.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#seo_h1_tag > a:nth-child(1)")).Enabled);
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
wait.Until(foo => foo.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._42ft._4jy0.FriendRequestAdd.addButton._4jy3._517h._51sy")).Enabled);
IWebElement invite = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._42ft._4jy0.FriendRequestAdd.addButton._4jy3._517h._51sy"));
        invite.Submit();
        invite.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
        } 
Dont work.

Comment: @MariuszBudzisz I don't have a visibility about `("#seo_h1_tag > a:nth-child(1)")`. What are your exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: 1-> go to Yagiellonian University facebook fanpage https://www.facebook.com/jagiellonian.university/
("#seo_h1_tag > a:nth-child(1)") is a logo of UJ, placed at the top of fanpage
2-> scroll down (don't work)
3-> push the "Add friend" button several times

Comment: I am afraid :( Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: hah, thanks for info m8 :)
Still, i just want to make a C# .NET Core 2.0 version of this: https://pythonicways.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/add-friends-on-facebook-python/

Comment: @MariuszBudzisz Shouldn't that be a separate question all together? Feel free to raise a new questionn with your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.