# Selecting a Iframe with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a program to login to my email account based on Selenium.
However I am running into the problem that a iframe Pop up will show with a button to continue and I am unable to select the button using Selenium.

The Website to login is: https://www.gmx.net/ which will switch you to this site/popup
https://www.gmx.net/consent-management/

The Button on the right "Akzeptieren und weiter" ( Accept and continue ) is not selectable through Selenium.

The code I am using is:

```
driver.get('https://www.gmx.net')
time.sleep(5)

driver.switchTo.frame(1)

time.sleep(5)

email_text_field5 =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="save-all-pur"]')
email_text_field5.click()


time.sleep(5)
```

I have also tried using:

```
email_text_field5 =  driver.find_element(By.ID, "save-all-pur")
email_text_field5.click()
```

however I am continuously running into the NoSuchElementException with both methods of selection
Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [13], line 12
     10 #driver.get('https://www.gmx.net/consent-management/')
     11 time.sleep(5)
---> 12 email_text_field5 =  driver.find_element(By.ID, "save-all-pur")
     13 email_text_field5.click()
     16 time.sleep(5)
```

The only other method to properly select the iframe is through ID however I can't seem to find any ID for this specific Iframe

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why dont find by.Xpath "//iframe"

Comment: Wehen using abc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(abc) I get the same nosuchelemtn exception on the driver.find_element(By.ID, "save-all-pur")

Comment: This is the HTML Code for the button in question I am trying to click <button data-v-4b7b2d4a="" id="save-all-pur" data-goto-view="" data-section="accept" class="btn btn-primary close-layer">
            Akzeptieren und weiter
          </button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Akzeptieren und weiter</kbd> is within nested `<frame>` / `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159359/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.gmx.net/consent-management/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://dl.gmx.net/permission/live/portal/v1/ppp/core.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://plus.gmx.net/lt']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#save-all-pur"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.gmx.net/consent-management/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://dl.gmx.net/permission/live/portal/v1/ppp/core.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://plus.gmx.net/lt')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='save-all-pur']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: gmx_net]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! Your solution worked perfectly. It also does make sense to include the src in the css selector to find the iframe. A lot of the solutions to similar problems on the web however don't include this as they almost always work with ID of Iframes. Thanks again