# Selenium: 'function' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am running into this issue when trying to click a button using selenium. The button html reads as below:

```
<button class="Component-button-0-2-65 Component-button-d1-0-2-68">and 5 more</button>
```

My code is here:

```
button = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//button[contains(@class,"Component-button-d")]'))
    if button:
        print("TRUE")
        button.click()
```

My output is:

```
TRUE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 47, in <module>
    button.click()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I am stumped as to why 'button' element is found by selenium (`print(True)` statement is executed) but then the `click()` method returns an attribute error.

This is the page I am scraping data from: https://religiondatabase.org/browse/regions
I am able to extract all the information I need on the page,  so the code leading up to the click is working.

I was expecting the item to be clickable. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the attribute error (function object has no attribute click). Because it I paste the xpath into the webpage, it highlights the correct element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element search is always done through the *`driver`* object which is the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) instance in it's core form:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")
```

But when you apply [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447), the *`wait`* configurations are applied on the *`driver`* object.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "element_xpath")))
```

So even during [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) the *`driver`* object needs to be present along with the [expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159359/7429447) and the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447).

---

### This usecase

This line of code:

```
button = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//button[contains(@class,"Component-button-d")]'))
```

button object references to a junk value but on probing returns *`true`* and prints ***TRUE*** but the click can't be performed as *`button`* is not of WebElement type.

---

### Solution

Given the HTML:

```
<button class="Component-button-0-2-65 Component-button-d1-0-2-68">and 5 more</button>
```

To click on the element  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* with *classname*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//button[contains(@class,'Component-button-d')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* with *classname* and *innerText*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'Component-button-d') and text()='and 5 more']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. I really appreciate it. I'll choose this answer as accepted since this provides more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. You can find below an example of how you can use Expected Conditions (along with WebdriverWait):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
## [...define your driver here, other imports etc]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

##[open a url, etc]
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="input-group"]')))
element.click()
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now understand what is wrong.